# How to connect MongoDB with Elastic Search using the ES plugin MongoDB river via Elastica

Tags: php, mongodb, elasticsearch, elastica

i'm new to programming, so i apologize, if my question is very simple.

First of all, I have installed and configured MongoDB and ES with MongoDB river, but i can't find how to do it via Elastica. My example is

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{ 
"type": "mongodb", 
"mongodb": { 
    "db": "testTweets", 
    "collection": "msgs"
}, 
"index": {
    "name": "mongoindex", 
    "type": "my_type" 
}
}'
```

and also a query is

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/mongoindex/_search?q=something&pretty=true'
```

How can i write them using PHP and Elastica?

I took as example

```
$elasticaType = $elasticaIndex->getType('tweet');
```

and i can't find how to match the curl command with the right php code.

I hope to be crystal clear! If you need any other to detail to give my a help, i will be very happy to add it.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT***

A nice way to compose ElasticSearch analysis or mapping is the following chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense/doinijnbnggojdlcjifpdckfokbbfpbo . It's very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way is to do it VIA PHP CURL ..